# What does $\frac {d}{d\sin(x)}\cos(x)$ geometrically represent?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $\frac {d}{dx}\cos(x)$ gives us a function which represents the slope of the function at each point, what does $\frac {d}{d\sin(x)}\cos(x)$ geometrically represent?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the rates of change.

$$ \Delta ( \cos x)  \approx ( \cos x)' \Delta x$$

And,

$$ \Delta ( \sin x) \approx (\sin x)' \Delta x$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{ \Delta \cos x}{\Delta \sin x} =  \frac{ (\cos x)'}{(\sin x)'} $$

In the limit as the 'input' difference between the points of the function which we took delta over reduces,

$$ \frac{ d \cos x}{ d \sin x} = \frac{ (\cos x)'}{(\sin x)'}= \frac{-\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Answer (score 0):

The circle $y^2+z^2=1$ can be parametrized as $y=\cos x,\,z=\sin x$. Then $\frac{d\cos x}{d\sin x}=\frac{dy}{dz}$ is the gradient of the tangent orthogonal to the radius from $(0,\,0)$ to $(z,\,y)$. Since the tangent is also perpendicular to the radius, which is of gradient $y/z$ if we plot $y$ against $z$ (so $x$ is a clockwise angle from the positive $y$-axis instead of the usual polar angle), the tangent is of gradient $-z/y$ as per @Burajan's calculation.